# merging two png images in php

Tags: php, image, gd

I am trying to merge my two images in php. One image is being uploaded frim my system and the other is the one I am creating with transparent background.
Here is my code. My code is just showing a non-image icon.
I don't understand where I am wrong.

```
    <?php
    //Set the Content Type
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    #dispaly the image
    $file=$_GET['file'];
    // echo file_get_contents($file);
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(250, 200);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $blue = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

    imagecolortransparent($im, $black);

    //text to draw
    $text="hello world";
    //font path
    $font = '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid/DroidSans.ttf';
    // Add the text
    imagettftext($im, 15, 0, 50, 50, $blue, $font, $text);

    $dest=imagecreatefrompng($file);
    $src=imagecreatefrompng($im);

    imagealphablending($dest, false);
    imagesavealpha($dest, true);

    imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 10, 10, 0, 0, 100, 250, 200);

    imagepng($dest);

    imagedestroy($dest);
    imagedestroy($src);

    ?>
```

Comment: Do not use `imagecreatefrompng` for `$im`

Comment: Black would be '0,0,0' rather than '255,255,255' I think.

Answer (score 0):

Use $im not $src - as Sayed pointed out, imagecreatefrompng takes filename (string) as argument - not GD resource. Why set $src if $im already contains GD resource ready for use?

There is important part with imagettftext. I was able to reproduce the effect of empty icon if GD cannot find a font in given path. Check your location, permissions and letter case. Also, if you decide to just copy the .ttf file right into script location, refer to [imagettftext() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) as there is important caveat with ".ttf" extension.

Also, to create fully transparent image use:
(by George Edison in [PHP doc for imagefill](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefill.php)

```
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(317, 196);
    $transparent =  imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagefill($im, 0, 0, $transparent);
    imagesavealpha($im, TRUE);
```

Also, from [PHP doc for imagecopymerge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php) by Sina Salek: imagecopymerge_alpha function to provide for true transperency in imagecopymerge()

So, my solution:

```
    <?php
    //Set the Content Type
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    #dispaly the image
    $file='test.png';

    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(317, 196);
    $transparent =  imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagefill($im, 0, 0, $transparent);
    imagesavealpha($im, TRUE);

    $blue = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 0, 0, 255, 0);

    //text to draw
    $text="hello world";
    putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));
    $font = 'lucida';
    imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 50, $blue, $font, $text);

    $dest=imagecreatefrompng($file);
    imagealphablending($dest, false);
    imagesavealpha($dest, true);

    imagecopymerge_alpha($dest, $im, 10, 10, 0, 0, 200, 180, 100);
    imagepng($dest);

    imagedestroy($dest);
    imagedestroy($im);

    function imagecopymerge_alpha($dst_im, $src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h, $pct){
        // creating a cut resource
        $cut = imagecreatetruecolor($src_w, $src_h);

        // copying relevant section from background to the cut resource
        imagecopy($cut, $dst_im, 0, 0, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_w, $src_h);

        // copying relevant section from watermark to the cut resource
        imagecopy($cut, $src_im, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h);

        // insert cut resource to destination image
        imagecopymerge($dst_im, $cut, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $src_w, $src_h, $pct);
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`imagecopymerge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php) function for this.

Find out link

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php
```